# Открыть ссылку в новом окне

Tags: javascript, popup

Есть список ссылок с атрибутом type="popup".

```js
document.querySelector("[type=popup]").onclick = function() {
window.open("this.href", "_blank", "width=600,height=600");

return false
}
```

```html
  <a type="popup" href="https://www.google.ru/">Google</a>
  <a type="popup" href="https://www.yandex.ru/">Яндекс</a>
```

После нажатия, нужно открыть ссылки в новом окне.

**Что Я делал:**

```
document.querySelector("[type=popup]").onclick = function() {
window.open("this.href", "_blank", "width=600,height=600");

return false
}
```

Окно открывается, но ссылка отсутствует, т.е ссылка есть this.href.

Как открыть ссылку в новом окне?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.querySelector("[type=popup]").onclick = function(e) {
    window.open(e.target.href, "_blank", "width=600,height=600");
    return false
}
```

Comment: Для списка ссылок не работает, только первая открывается `querySelectorAll` не помогает.

Answer (score 0):

Список ссылок обвернул в класс. Объект передал для селектора. Все элементы открываются в новом окне.

```
<div class="♥">
<a href="https://www.google.ru/">Google</a>
<a href="https://www.yandex.ru/">Яндекс</a>
</div>
<script>
var listHref = document.getElementsByClassName('♥');
    listHref = document.querySelector("*").onclick = function(e) {
               window.open(e.target.href, "_blank", "width=600,height=600");

    return false
}
</script>
```